# Lebesgue Measure in ${R}^m$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to solve the following problem.

*Problem Statement*

If $E \subset \mathrm{R}^m$ and $\lambda_m\left(E\right) >1 $, where $\lambda_m$ is the Lebesgue measure on ${R}^m$, then there are two distinct points $x, x^1 \in E$ such that the differences between the corresponding coordinates are integers.

*Some Thoughts towards proof*

Since Lebesgue measure is translation invariant, we can relocate the set $E$ while preserving it's measure, such that one of it's vertex relocates to the origin/zero vector in the $Z^m$ point lattice/Grid. The relocation causes an equal shift for all points in $E$ where the shift is a vector $s \in [0, 1)^m$.

I suppose now, if I can show that there is a point in this relocated set with the Euclidean norm as an integer, I would be done, but I am not quite sure how to proceed further.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A rewording without talking about quotients]

If $x\in\mathbb{R}$ then $x-\lfloor x\rfloor\in[0,1)$ is an integer translation.

Apply this translation to all coordinates of all points of $E$. The transformation consists in translating each size-one cube $[a_1,a_1+1)\times...\times[a_n,a_n+1)$ with $a_1,...,a_n\in\mathbb{Z}$ to the cube $[0,1)^n$. If $E$ were mapped injectively (no part of $E$ falls on top of another), then the image of $E$ would have the same volume as $E$. But $E$ has volume $>1$, while $[0,1)^n$ has volume $1$. It doesn't fit.

Therefore $E$ is not mapped injectively by this transformation. Therefore at least two of its points differ by an integer translation.

Actually this shows that there must be set of this type of points of positive measure. So, there are a lot of them.

Comment: This doesn't seem so clear to me, since there are uncountable sets of measure 0.  How do we know that $\pi$ doesn't "fold" $E$ (or at least parts of it) into a Cantor set?

Comment: @nomen the folding here is not some mysterious folding, it is just integer translations.

Comment: But you say there isn't an injective map $\pi$ from $R^n$ to the torus.  But there is, since we can show that a cantor set has the same cardinality as $E$.

Comment: @nomen No, the claim is that the specific map $\pi$, the quotient map, is the one that is not injective on $E$.

Comment: @JLA The explanation is in the answer. The map is just a bunch of translations of the pieces of $E$ that fall in different parts of the grid, to the cell $[0,1]^n$. If the pieces do not fall one on top of the other, the area they cover is the same as the original one. But the original one is assumed to have area $>1$, which is larger than the area of $[0,1]^n$. Impossible.